# How to build 32-bit Qt5 application on 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gcc, qt5, 32bit-64bit

I have currently got the 64-bit version of Qt5 installed on a 64-bit Ubuntu machine but I'd also like to be able to do 32-bit builds on the same machine. On Windows I can simply select additional kits in the MaintenanceTool but on Linux this doesn't seem to be possible. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You have to install 32-bit version of compiler and libraries. There are many answers on this site.

Comment: go to tool->options->build and run, in kit tab then clone existing kit and change the compiler to GCC( 32bit), you will get usefull warning/success For me I am getting warning that "For the compiler to use for the building. Make sure the compiler to produce binaries compatible with the target device, Qt versions and other libraries used"

Comment: Thanks. I can choose the 32-bit GCC but my problem is that I don't have a 32-bit version of Qt and I'm not sure how I should be installing that. As I said, the Windows installer has an option for this but the Linux one doesn't.

Comment: Try [Qt Online Installers](https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) or build Qt from source yourself. It might be that they don't provide 32bit Qt binaries for linux.

Comment: + while build from source, you need to configure which version of the Qt library to build using following command "./configure -platform linux-g++-32"

Answer (score 1):

Three steps:

1. Get the 32 bit version [from Qt](https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) or [build from source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html) with `./configure -platform linux-g++-32`.
2. Make sure it gets installed to a different path than the 64-bit version. Can be achieved with something like `./configure -platform linux-g++-32 -prefix /opt/qt32` or the path that feels comfortable to you.
3. Fix compiler settings [along these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820934/compiling-32-bit-qt-applications-on-a-64-bit-linux-os) for building the application